# Any idea why my polling doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs

I have a this script:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies']);

app.service('FetchTeams', function($http, $interval) {
    this.url = 'data.json';

    this.fetch = function() {        
        return $http.get(this.url)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                })
                .catch(function(response) {
                    console.log('Error retrieving team data', response.status, response.data);
                });
    };

    this.startPolling = function(cb) {
                            this.fetch.then(cb);
                            $interval(function() { this.fetch().then(cb) }.bind(this), 60000); // start 1 min interval
                        };

    this.endLongPolling = function() { 
                            $interval.cancel(this.startPolling);
                          };    
});

app.controller('appcontroller', function($scope, FetchTeams) {
    FetchTeams.startPolling(function(data) {
        $scope.nflteams         = data.nflteams;
        $scope.nhlteams         = data.nhlteams;
        $scope.nbateams         = data.nbateams;
        $scope.mlbteams         = data.mlbteams;
    });
});
```

On lines 16 - 18, it should be polling data.json, but it currently isn't. Any idea what i'm doing what?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code must be in the question itself. Not at pastebin.

Comment: Sorry about that.. done

Comment: What is `FetchTeams.startPolling`?  That's nowhere in your service definition.

Comment: Just updated the script. it was originally startPolling(), but i changed it to polling() - unfortunately that didn't fix it =(

Comment: FYI, the interval time is in milliseconds. Making a GET request every 20 milliseconds is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this in the wrong contexts:

For example when you do:

```
         $http.get(this.url)
```

this does not have the url property because it points to the created function.

Try this:

```
    this.url = 'data.json';
    var that = this;

    this.fetch = function() {        
        return $http.get(that.url)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                })
                .catch(function(response) {
                    console.log('Error retrieving sales data', response.status, response.data);
                });
    };
```

You have that error two or three times in the whole script.

Comment: So `this.url = 'data.json';  var that = this; ...  return $http.get(that.url)` ? That didn't work for me

Comment: @BobbyBruce Like he said, you have this issue in multiple places. Basically, wherever you reference `this` inside another function.